# DLL control images and memory usage

Tags: c#, controls, custom-controls, picturebox

I made a unique control, it involves a clickable picturebox, a text box, and a label. The label is auto updated based on an inputable string, the picturebox is basically a check box that turns on and off and the textbox accept generic text input. For this example I will call this control "MyControl".

My question is, I set an the picturebox's images at runtime. In the DLL is public Image imgYes, and public Image imgNo. In the form the DLL in referenced into, I have imgChecked and imgUnChecked, which I then assing MyControl.imgYes = imgChecked, and MyControl.imgNo = imgUnChecked.

I draw the control 20 times in the form, but I was curious - if I embeded the image into the DLL so it was an internal reference instead of needing to be referenced at runtime, would running 20 instances of the control mark 20 imgYes and imgNo files, meaning 40 images in the stack, or would it all reference the DLL running only 2 images (same as my referencing imgChecked).